# Eigenvalues of a rank-one update to a rank-one matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be two column vectors in $\mathbb{C}^N$. What can we say about the eigenvalues of the matrix
\begin{align}
\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^H+\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{a}^H$ represents conjugate transpose of $\mathbf{a}$ and so on.

Comment: $a^H$ means the transpose of the column vector $a$ right?

Comment: I believe it is the conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a=\|\mathbf{a}\|$ and $b=\|\mathbf{b}\|$. By an orthogonal change of basis, one may assume that $\mathbf{a}^H=(a,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $\mathbf{b}^H=(b\bar{x},b\bar{y})$ with $|x|^2+|y|^2=1$. Hence
$$
M = \mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^H + \mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H
=\pmatrix{
a^2 + b^2|x|^2 &b^2x\bar{y}\\
b^2\bar{x}y    &b^2|y|^2} \oplus 0_{n-2}.
$$
It follows that apart from $n-2$ zero eigenvalues, the other two eigenvalues of $M$ are the two roots of $z^2-(a^2+b^2)z+a^2b^2|y|^2=z^2-\left(\|\mathbf{a}\|^2+\|\mathbf{b}\|^2\right)z+\left(\|\mathbf{a}\|^2\|\mathbf{b}\|^2-|\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{b}|^2\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First, by looking at rank, you can say something about the number of non-zero eigenvalues.  Second, your matrix will be Hermetian, and we can say something about the eigenvalues of such a matrix.  Third, the trace will be $|a|^2+|b|^2$.  Combined with the first two observations, this will let you say a little more about the eigenvalues.

Comment: $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=|a|^2+|b|^2$ and $\lambda_i\geq 0$ and $\lambda_i=0,~\forall i=3,\dots,N$. Unfortunately, I already know this. I was looking for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Comment: You asked what could we say without saying what you knew or what you were hoping might be true. Consider modifying your question.